# compiler doesnt ask for any input

Tags: python, input, python-3.4

i'm trying to flip the bits of a 32-bit binary number
but somehow its not working properly. it doesnt even ask for an input. i dont know whats going on.

```
    def flip_bits(k):
    for j in range(len(k)):
        if k[i] == 1:
            k[i] = 0
        elif k[i] == 0:
            k[i] = 1
    print(k)

if __name__ == '__init__':
    t = int(input())
    a = []
    b = []
    for i in range(t):
        a.append(int(input()))
        b.append(bin(a[i])[2:].zfill(32))
    flip_bits(b)
```

if i remove the if **name** = '**init**' part it takes the input but doesn't give me an appropriate output can u please direct me in the right path?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__init__':` should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: BTW, you might want to have a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score 1):

It should be `__main__` not `__init__`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

[what-does-if-name-main-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)